# Mupdf Annotation not working in lollipop 5.0

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop pdf-reader using mupdf library.

It works up to android version 4.4.2 but not works on lollipop 5.0 or higher.

Following is error I am facing :

```
 08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: illegal class name 'android.graphics.PointF'
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     (should be of the form 'package/Class', [Lpackage/Class;' or '[[B')
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to FindClass
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.addMarkupAnnotationInternal(android.graphics.PointF[], int)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=18 Runnable
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d56ee0 self=0xb90bd420
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=8904 nice=10 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb90bd900
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xa444d000-0xa444f000 stackSize=1036KB
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004f60  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00256ad1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 00239687  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+158)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b1a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+610)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b2165  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b6197  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::FindClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+66)
    08-13 11:37:33.134: A/art(8754): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 00024c03  /data/app/jp.co.iti.mymupdfsample-1/lib/arm/libmupdf.so (Java_com_artifex_mupdfdemo_MuPDFCore_addMarkupAnnotationInternal+258)
```

this is my MuPDFCore.java code http://pastebin.com/8nyGA2hq

Please give proper solution as i am not able to debug and find where is the error in my code.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the Java code you posted. It looks like it's in the FindClass call in your C/C++ `Java_com_artifex_mupdfdemo_MuPDFCore_addMarkupAnnotationInternal` function. Looks like it uses this sort of name search:

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android.graphics.PointF");
```

But it be using this style:

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/graphics/PointF");
```

Maybe the dots worked on 4.4, seems dubious but maybe. 5.0 ART made JNI definitely more fickle, it crashes out on a lot of spec-violations that Dalvik put up with.

Comment: I am try jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/graphics/PointF");

Comment: Make sure you've definitely rebuilt and included the rebuild JNI code in there. The error it gives now can't be the same as the stacktrace in your original post.

Comment: How to rebuild jni file from eclipse

Comment: If it's Eclipse then there's probably an Android.mk file too. In that case, rebuild the library with ndk-build from the Android NDK. I don't know if you can do this from Eclipse, you might have to use the command line. Afterwards rebuild the Java/APK part with Eclipse.